# mysql error 1360, cannot drop trigger. is this a bug?

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER carslibrary_trigger
    AFTER insert ON carslibrary
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      insert into facerecord (carslibrary_ID) values (new.CarID);
END$$

delimiter;
```

i am trying to delete my trigger

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0087 sec)
SELECT trigger_name
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE event_object_table =  'carslibrary'
AND action_timing =  'AFTER'
AND event_manipulation =  'INSERT'
LIMIT 0 , 30

drop trigger carslibrary_trigger;

#1360 - Trigger does not exist
DROP trigger carslibrary_trigger;
```

my query returned a record, but it can't drop?

why i can't drop my trigger?

i also made a general query still returns 1 record

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0606 sec)
SELECT * 
FROM  `TRIGGERS` 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of MySQL? You may have to include table name.

```
DROP TRIGGER carslibrary.carslibrary_trigger;
```

Comment: Try the above then, in v <5.0.10 I believe the table name is required.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get this issue using MyISAM engine, check the TRN files in the data folder, in my case those were there, even though I deleted the trigger using command line.

Manually Deleting TRN files of the triggers that are throwing error 1360 will solve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

if the error `trigger does not exist`  with error code 1360 occurs,
simply execute the triggers from command line

`mysql -u root -p`
then `mysql> execute the triggers`

then check the information_schema in mysql

the triggers can be viewed there

just edit table data